# Branch-and-Price: return gap using SCIP

Tags: python, solver, branch-and-bound, branch-and-price, scip

I implemented a branch-and-price tree in python.

I would like to stop the process after 5 hours and return the gap in % between the best integer solution found so far and the optimal solution.

How do I give a value to SCIP and ask how far in % is that from the optimal value?

EDIT: To those interested the question can now be found on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522580/stop-branch-and-price-tree-and-return-gap

Comment: welcome! with SCIP specific questions you may be better off with the SCIP mailing list or on stack overflow under #SCIP tag.

SCIP returns a dual and a primal bound, and even the gap in percent in the output, let me understand why this is not sufficient.

Comment: To piggyback off of what @MarcoLübbecke said, questions about specific solvers are _in scope_ here (see [this post](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/should-program-solver-package-specific-questions-be-allowed)). It's possible you'll have more luck getting an answer on the platforms that Marco suggested, but I hope you get an answer here. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll try post it on Stack Overflow. I can't return the gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepted answer from the cross-post: [Stop Branch-and-Price tree and return gap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61522580/8239061)

> You can easily compute this yourself: `SCIPgetDualbound` will return you
> the best (global) dual bound, and `SCPgetPrimalbound` will give you the
> best primal bound.    -[Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11158393/leon)

<sub>Will delete this CW if [Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11158393/leon) posts answer here.</sub>